# SET exercise:How many students did the third exercise if...?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

There are 100 students in an exam.Only 3 of them haven't done any exercise.

65 students did first or third exercise,and 61 students did second or third exercise.

Zero students did first and second exercise.

How many students did the third exercise?

Comment: You have used the "inclusion-exclusion" tag... Maybe you have to use the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: Let $A_i$ the set of those student that did $ui$-exercise. According to first statement, $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3|= 97$

Comment: And we know that $|A_1 \cup A_3|=65$ and that $|A_2 \cup A_3|=61$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is given that zero students did first and second exercise. The second exercise will have only two parts which contain those students who did only second exercise and who did only second and third exercise. Zero students did all 3 exercise.

Let the students who did only second exercise be p and the total students who did third exercise be q. The students who only did first exercise be r.

We have

r+q=65 (1)

p+q=61 (2)

r+p+q=97 (3)

From these 3 equations we have q= 29.